# IP in the browser bar and not the Name of the domain (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I am using a EC2 to create a wordpress webpage. I have created this instance with and elastic IP assigned but now I have a problem.

I have bought the domain in a external webpage ... I assigned to this domain the elastic IP of my EC2 instance but when I enter in the webpage what **I see in the browser bar is the IP of the webpage and not the name of the webpage**.

I have seen tutorials and I have changed in wp-config.php this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

for:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mywebpage.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://mywebpage.com');
```

But still doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot :) !!!

Comment: What is the URL? Can you paste it?

Comment: Did you replace your IP address in DB?

Comment: what is written in <title> tags of your site?

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys!

@Vel I haven't replaced my IP address in DB. Can I make it trought ssh? Where can I find the file to replace it?

Comment: @EriksKlotins do you mean the name of the site?

Comment: please install phpmyadmin to replace or use any plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/

Comment: @Vel ok thank you Vel, I am going to do it and tell you if this works! I installed this plug-in, but with this I only can see the tables.

Comment: simply download your DB and replace all your url to new domain and import again.

Comment: @JCJunior Browser takes contents of the <title> tags to display name of the website. If that value is not available, domain or url is used.

Comment: @Vel I am using the plug-in but when I create the online database I can't access. Where could I see my admin credentials? (sorry but the first time doing this)

Comment: @Vel I have it online with this plug-in. But I have to access using my credentials

Comment: @Vel through SSH the systems says "Permission Denied" :|

Comment: you know how to use mysql in ssh?

Comment: do you have wp-admin access?

Comment: @Vel I haven't use it but I can try it. I am the admin of this wordpress so the credentials have to be user and my pass. Right?

Comment: Yes. go to admin panel settings->general-> update the site url and home url

Comment: @Vel I can't do it by the web. I have to do it by SSH and I have changed this using SSH but have to be something in Database like we are talking!

Comment: @Vel can you help me? I have now access to phpmyadmin via SSH tunel with my admin credentials. What should I change or look for in phpmyadmin??

Comment: You try check in Database table wp_options field WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME again

Comment: @Vel thank you again! I change it in database but still continues the same error :(

Comment: what is the site url?

Answer (score 0):

You try check in Database table wp_options field WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME again

after that found a same issue check on DNS provider check Nameserver correct or wrong

Comment: Thank you Montree for your respone. What file should I edit to make this??